# Single Column vs Multi Column Design (for Non Primary Key columns)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, database-design, nosql

In database table design, which of the following is better design for event-log type of data growth

> Design 1) Numeric columns(Long) and character columns (Varchar2) with
>   Index:

```
..(pkey)|..|..|StockNumber Long | StockDomain Varchar2 |...
..      |..|..|11111            | Finance
..      |..|..|23458            | Medical
```

> Design 2) Character column Varchar2 with Index:

```
..(pkey)|..|..|StockDetails  Varchar2(1000) |..|..
..      |..|..|11111;Finance                |..|.. 
..      |..|..|23458;Medical                |..|..
```

Design advantages: First design is very specific and Second design is more general which can accommodate more general data.In both the cases, columns indexed.

Storage: First design indexes require less storage than second
Performance: Same?

I am having a question about performance vs flexibility. Obviously, first design is better. But second design is the more general purpose. Let me know your insights

Note: Edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: The advantages of using one column are this: don't ever use one column. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you use a database system like Oracle you should store it in the right format, i.e. seperate coumns. Otherwise you better use a flat file (or Hadoop). When you think that #2 is *more general* you will finally end with all data in a single table :-)

Comment: But seriously though the performance won't be the same in any database operation as you will have to include a function to split every string you insert into the monolithic column. Proper indexing won't be possible, leading to more performance issues. Readability and usability are worse. Anyone that has to use processes relating to this will also have a lower life span. I can keep going.

Comment: Six months later you want to add another column of data. Design (1) makes this trivial to do. Design (2) will have all sorts of nasty problems. Eventually you'll need to store, within each row, some kind of metadata. Then, too late, you'll realise you've fallen afoul of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect.

Comment: Please review the question one more time. There were edits. Please recommend. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, having discrete columns is the better way to go for a few reasons:

1. Datatypes - You have guarantees that the data you have saved is in the right formats, at least as far as non string columns go, your stockNumber will always be a number if it's a bigint/long, trying to set it to anything else will cause your insert/update to error. As part of a colon separated value (CSV) string there is a chance of bad data when it's part of a string.
2. Querying - Querying a single column has to be done using `LIKE` since you are looking for a substring of the single column string. If I look for `WHERE StockDetails LIKE '%11111%'` I will find the first line, but I may find another line where a dollar value inside that column, in a different field is $11111. With discrete columns your query would be `WHERE StockNumber = 11111` guaranteeing it finds the data only in that column.
3. Using the data - Once you have found the row you're wanting, you then have to read the data. This means parsing out your CSV into separate fields. If one of those fields had a colon in it, and it is improperly escaped, the rest of the data is going to be parsed wrong, and you still need your values in a guaranteed same order, leaving blank sections `;;` where you would have had a null value in a column.

There is a middle ground between storing CSVs and a separate columns. I have seen, and in fact am doing on one major project, data stored in a table as json. With json you have property names, so you don't care the order the fields appear in the string, because domain will still always be domain, any non standard fields you don't need in an entry (say a property that only exists for the medical domain) will just not be there rather than needing a blank double colon, and parsers for json exist in all languages I can think of that you would connect to your database, there's no need to manually code something to parse out your CSV string. For example your StockDetails given above would look like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|             StockDetails             |
+--------------------------------------+
| {"number":11111, "domain":"Finance"} |
| {"number":23458, "domain":"Medical"} |
+--------------------------------------+
```

This solves issues 2 and 3 above:

2. You now write your query as `WHERE StockDetails LIKE '%"number":11111` including the json property name guarantees you don't find the data anywhere else in your string.
3. You don't need to worry about fields out of order, or missing in your string causing your data to be unusable, using json gives you the key/value pair, all you need to do is handle nulls where the key doesn't exist. This also lets you add fields easily, adding a new CSV field can break your code to parse it, the number of values will be off for your existing data, so you will need to update all rows potentially, however since in json you only store non null fields, a new field will be treated like any other null value on existing data.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for the response. Please revisit my question. I have few edits. I did not realize my question has ambiguous meaning. The columns that I mentioned are trivial columns in my requirement

Comment: Andrew, I like your thought process. Json is very effective for structured data. CSV is also a semi structured data for non trivial columns, and length of the string matters for indexed data. Very conservative about the column length (Hardly 1000 chars). Avoiding relational foreign keys could make the tables lightweight and general purpose. Great answer. Thanks a lot. After seeing NoSQL/Bigdata data designs (Domain Driven Designs), I am relearning my database schema design knowledge. Focus is for simplicity rather complexity.

Comment: @user-name-infinity As an additional benefit to using json in your column, you can do queries on that column with less risk of bad substring matches, since you have the field name in the json your query is now `LIKE '%"domain":"Medical"%'`

Comment: Andrew, I showed this discussion to my colleague. He got confused. Could you please re-edit your answer for the updated question. This discussion may help others too

Comment: @user-name-infinity I hope that clears it up, I condensed the original section based on your question looking like it would be a single column table to include only what still mattered for a CSV string, and cleared up the rest, if your college has specific questions, ask them and I will help however i can.

Answer (score 2):

In relational database design, you need discrete columns. One value per column per row.

This is the only way to use data types and constraints to implement some data integrity. In your second design, how would you implement a UNIQUE constraint on either StockNumber or StockDomain? How would you make sure StockNumber is actually a number?

This is the only way to create indexes on each column individually, or create a compound index that puts the StockDomain first.

As an analogy, look in the telephone book: can you find all people whose first name is "Bill" easily or efficiently? No, you have to search the whole book to find people with a specific first name. The order of columns in an index matters.

The second design is practically not a database at all — it's a *file*.

---

To respond to your comments, I'm reiterating what I wrote in a comment:

Sometimes denormalization is worthwhile, but I can't tell [if your second design is worthwhile], because you haven't described how you will query this data. You must take into account your query needs before you can decide on any optimization.

Stated another way: denormalization, like all other optimizations, benefits one query type, *at the expense of other query types.* Therefore you need to know which queries you need to be optimal, and which queries are less important, so it won't hurt your overall performance if the other queries are degraded.

If you can't predict the queries, default to designing a database with rules of normalization. Normalization is not designed for performance optimization, it's designed to prevent data anomalies, which is a good goal too.

---

You have posted several new comments, I guess in the hopes that I will suddenly understand and endorse your second design. But you still haven't described any specific query that will be optimized by using your second design.

Comment: Bill Karwin thank you for the quick response. I have edited the question for more clarity. The columns that I mentioned are trivial, but general purpose table has some advantage with untraditionally growing data. Excuse me for the edits, but I did not realize there are ambiguous details in my question. In your experience, what is a good use of column with text and indexed? Indexed columns have O(log(n)) search performance in the worst case. Columnizing every data is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Sometimes denormalization is worthwhile, but I can't tell because you haven't described how you will query this data. You must take into account your query needs before you can decide on any optimization.

Comment: Bill, Can you be specific. For example if what if I have only 1000 char limit and query don't use % in the query. Do you consider Design-2 is a good design?

Comment: No, I don't consider the second design to be a good design. You haven't shown an example query for which the second design has any advantage. It's not a good idea to sacrifice the ability to use data types, constraints, and indexes, unless you have a very specific use case that can't be solved any other way.

Comment: Bill, we need to give multiple perspectives to readers on the design. When to choose which design. Volume/Velocity/Variety is a big advantage of Bigdata.  But RDBMS can also get such requirements in very rare occasions. So we can not use stick to same ideas. If you see evolution of data storage , files, dbms, RDBMS, nosql, Bigdata ... Every solution is great and served humanity. If I have small VVV problem we need not to go to Bidata/NoSQL databases. It is very expressive to companies. So we can leaverage same database for accommodating VVV types of data.

Comment: I made a mistake with my first edited question. Could you please reedit your answer. You may stick to your perspective. After my edits to question, the entire question changed from flat table record to non-primary column focus. You Dan treat my question is new. Our discussion may cause confusions to readers.

Comment: @user-name-infinity, Whether the columns you're describing are primary keys or not makes no difference to my answer. I have added more text above to explain further.